# [JS/NODEJS ]Error al declarar una variable dentro de un bloque de try catch

Tags: javascript, nodejs

-----help.js----

```
exports.run = async (command_s, Discord, message, client) => {
  // temporal
  const command = "profile";

  function string(){
      try{x = require(`./commands/utility/${command}`+'.js'); var result = x;return result;}catch(err){};
      try{y = require(`./command/fun/${command}`+'.js'); var result = y;return result;}catch(err){};
  }

  const x = await string()
  console.log(x)
  const final_message = x.info()
  console.log(final_message)

}
```

Quiero hacer un sistema que comprueba en que "carpeta" esta localizada el archivo mediante un try/catch , pero al llamar la variable 'result' me devuelve : "undefined". 
Después quiero poder llamar de esa var "x"  la función 'info()' , la cual devuelve un string :
------profile.js-----

```
function info(){
   return "Obtén la información sobre tu perfil"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la idea, pero necesitas pulir un poco más. En primer lugar debes usar los bloques `try/catch` anidados, es decir, uno dentro de otro.

Te comento lo que yo haría, y espero que te ayude:

```js
exports.run = async (command_s, Discord, message, client) => {
  // temporal
  const command = "profile";

  // Nuestra función acepta como parámetro un valor
  // así podremos reutilizarla si hiciera falta
  function string(command) {
    try {
      
      // Declaro mi variable dentro de la función
      const x = require(`./commands/utility/${command}`+'.js'); // <== no se si realmente necesitas agregar la extensión
      // Si 'require()' se ejecuta correctamente devuelvo la variable
      // Pero si hay un error, el bloque 'catch' se ejecutará
      return x;
      } catch(err1) { // Notemos que este error se llama 'err1'
        // Si llegamos aqui, entonces lo anterior falló
        console.log('err1: ', err1.message);
        
        // Aqui ponemos nuestro segundo 'try/catch'
        // a esto se le llama 'anidado'
        try {
        
          // Nuevamente declaro la variable local
          const y = require(`./command/fun/${command}`+'.js'); // <== no se si realmente necesitas agregar la extensión
          
          // Si 'require()' se ejecuta correctamente devuelvo la variable
          // Pero si hay un error, el bloque 'catch' se ejecutará
          return y;
          } catch(err2) { // Notemos que este error se llama 'err2'
      
            // Si llegamos aqui, entonces lo anterior falló
            // Devolvemos null (aunque puedes devolver otra cosa
            // Eso lo decides segun la lógica de tu programa)
            console.log('err2: ', err2.message);
            return null;
          } // Fin catch(err2)
        } // Fin catch (err1)
    }//Fin funcion string()
  
  // Ahora podemos declarar una variable que contenga
  // el resultado de nuestra funcion, la llamare perfil
  
  const perfil = await string(command);
  
  // Ahora verificamos que efectivamente modulo contiene un módulo
  
  if (!perfil) {
    console.log('Hubo un error al hacer \'require()\'');
  } else {
    perfil.info();
  }
  
} // Fin async
```

Así ya tienes una forma muy básica de comprobar en que carpeta se encuentra tu archivo.

Hay muchas herramientas que pudieras usar para esta tarea, pero tal vez solo requieras esto para solucionar tu problema.

Saludos.